# Creating a vector of matrices of different dimension in R

Tags: r

How can I create a vector of matrices of different dimension in R. For example say I have two matrices

```
M1=array(0,dim=c(2,2))
M2=array(0,dim=c(3,3))
```

Then I can make a vector C containing these matrices such that

```
C[1]=M1
```

and

```
C[2]=M2.
```

I know that I can create a 3 dimensional array

```
C=array(NA,dim=c(2,3,3)
```

but the only way I know how to do this has to have the

```
C[1,,]
```

element in the array have more space then necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a list

```
C <- list()
C[[1]] <- array(0,dim=c(2,2))
C[[2]] <- array(0,dim=c(3,3))
C[[1]][1,1] <- 5
C[[1]]
C[[2]]
```